# How to show only one value of one value in a list

Tags: python, text-files

I have a problem, I want the program to only show the highest score for each person in the list. Within the text file, there are 3 peoples names e.g. Tom, James and Dave, and there scores, so it will look like this.

```
Tom,9
Tom,8
Tom,2
James,9
James,4
James,0
```

I want the program to show the highest score for that person in alphabetical order. Below is the program that i have got, but i can only get it to print out there highest scores in descending order, and it showing all the scores, not just the highest for that person.

```
def alpha():
    n = 0
    fo = open("class1.txt" , "r")
    ab = fo.readlines()
    y = len(ab)
    list1 = []
    for y in range(0,y):
        a = ab.pop()
        number = a.split(",")
        b = number.pop()
        b = int(b)
        list1.extend([(number,b)])
        list1.sort(key=lambda list1: list1[1], reverse = True)
    print(list1)




alpha()
```

If you could help out, that would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: I assume this is python code ?

Comment: Yes. This is Python 3.3.2 code.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a case for `dict`.

Read in each name, look if it's already in your dictionary; set `dictionary[name] = b` if (and only if) either `name` is not yet in the dictionary or `b` is bigger than what's already in the dictionary.

printing out sorted is as easy as

```
for name in sorted(dictionary.keys(), reverse=True):
    print name, dictionary[name]
```

(though there's a million ways to achieve this)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    values = f.read().split()
    scores = {}
    for item in values:
        item = item.split(',')
        if item[0] in scores.keys():
            scores[item[0]].append(item[1])
        else:
            scores[item[0]] = [item[1]]
high_scores = [[key, max(scores[key])] for key in scores.keys()]
high_scores.sort()

for item in high_scores:
    print "{}: {}".format(item[0], item[1])
```

---

```
James: 9
Tom: 9
>>>
```

Comment: This could go terribly wrong if there are spaces in the lines. Better do `for line in f`? Also, you could unpack as `name, score = item.split(',')`

Comment: @tobias_k, the split will split it properly even with spaces in the lines.

Comment: I mean, if there is a line like `"Tom, 23"`, won't this result in tokens `[..., "Tom,", "23", ...]`, which it will then again try to split at the `,`? It works well for the example (+1), but might be a bit more robust.